# How to get an array of Sitecore Sibling Items?

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

I want to get an array of all the sibling items of the current item so that I can display the thumbnails in them. how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get parent item of the current item and then take all its children except from the current item.

You can use code below:

```cs
Item currentItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
Item[] siblings = currentItem.Parent.GetChildren().Where(c => c.ID != currentItem.ID).ToArray();
```